# Как остановить цикл при нахождении определенного объекта на странице

Tags: python, парсер

Программа не останавливается и скролит дальше, надо чтобы она остановилась на определенном объекте, как это сделать?

```
while True:
    try:
        while await page.locator('mt-30.btn-pager').is_visible() is False:
            #await page.mouse.wheel(0, 1100)
            await page.keyboard.down('End')

            if await page.locator('.mt-30.btn-pager').is_visible() is True:
                await page.click('.mt-30.btn-pager')

    except Exception as err:
        print(err, 'Все вышло, я прошел сайт')
        break

categories_with_medicines_1 = (
    await page.query_selector_all(".product-hor.mb-10.js-stateProduct"))

for i in categories_with_medicines_1:
    data_id = await i.get_attribute('data-id')
    print(data_id)
    data_name = await i.get_attribute('data-name')
    print(data_name)
    data_url = await i.get_attribute('data-url')
    print(data_url)
    json_file.append({
        'data_id': data_id,
        'data_name': data_name,
        'data_url': data_url
    })
```